# How to link to the current User/Author Profile page?

Tags: author, profiles

Is there a way to link to the authors profile page?

At the moment i can access the authors profile by visiting the url like this:

http://mysite.com/?author=1

Is there a function that i could use to show this link regardless if the permalinks are changed?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

if i am guessing it right you need to use `<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>` function to link to the author page

**Note:** Remember the function will only be useful if you want to link to the author of a post not a particular user

**Source:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_posts_link

Comment: if this works for you please mark it as correct answer by clicking the tick button left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Author Templates on the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) explains about author profiles. I think you may want `the_author_link()` which you could set up to link whatever you want.